# Does Extension Relationship Permissions as ACLs work on CiviCRM 5.2.3?

Tags: permissions, relationships, compatiblity

The Extension says it is Compatible with CiviCRM 4.7.

It seems to work with CiviCRM 5.2.3, but am I safe using it?

I did notice one side-effect - when this extension is enabled I can't edit the permissions on existing Relationships.  The little AJAX spinner never stops.  Is this a known effect, or is it related to the CiviCRM version?

Answer (score 1):

Email from the author says:

"Yes - it should work on the latest 5.x release. I'll remove the reference to 4.7 as 5.3 was a security release & < 5.3 is not secure.
I merged changes recently that probably mean the current version needs 5.4+ - I'd have to check."

Comment: I conform this is working fine on 5.5.1.